# Mongodb docker container with client access control

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to create a docker container with a mongodb configured with client access control (user authentication, see [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/enable-authentication/)).

I have successfully configured a docker container with mongo using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/). But it doesn't use mongo access control.

The problem is that to enable access control I have to run mongodb with a specific command line (`--auth`) but only after creating the first admin user.

With a standard mongodb installation I normally perform these steps:

- run mongod without `--auth`
- connect to mongo and add the admin user
- restart mongo with `--auth`

How I'm supposed to do it with docker? Because mongo image always start without `--auth`. Should I create a new image? Or maybe modify the entry point?

Probably I'm missing something, I'm new to docker...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. Basically MongoDb has a feature that allow to setup access security (`--auth`) but permit localhost connection.
See [mongo local exception](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/security-users/#localhost-exception).

So this is my final script:

```
# Create a container from the mongo image, 
#  run is as a daemon (-d), expose the port 27017 (-p),
#  set it to auto start (--restart)
#  and with mongo authentication (--auth)
# Image used is https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
docker pull mongo
docker run --name YOURCONTAINERNAME --restart=always -d -p 27017:27017 mongo mongod --auth

# Using the mongo "localhost exception" add a root user

# bash into the container
sudo docker exec -i -t YOURCONTAINERNAME bash

# connect to local mongo
mongo

# create the first admin user
use admin
db.createUser({user:"foouser",pwd:"foopwd",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})

# exit the mongo shell
exit
# exit the container
exit

# now you can connect with the admin user (from any mongo client >=3 )
#  remember to use --authenticationDatabase "admin"
mongo -u "foouser" -p "foopwd" YOURHOSTIP --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are able to use other existing images, there is a well maintained image with default authentication enabled for MongoDB and easy to plug in, called [**tutum-docker-mongodb**](https://github.com/tutumcloud/mongodb).

It also uses environmental variables which you can use in you app.

I included it in my `tutum.yml` (or `docker-compose.yml`) like so:

```
mongo:
  image: 'tutum/mongodb:latest'
  environment:
    - MONGODB_PASS=<your-password-here>
  ports:
    - '27017:27017'
    - '28017:28017'
```

Finally I linked the web service using:

```
web:
  image: 'my-image'
  links:
    - 'mongo:mongo'
  ports:
    - '80:3000'
  restart: always
```

Hope it helps!