# How to enable MongoDB access control using a Docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, dockerhub

I'm using a `Dockerfile` in combination with a `docker-compose.yml` to start two services:

- My app service
- A MongoDB service

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
build: .
ports:
  - "80:3000"
environment:
  NODE_ENV: production
links:
  - mongo
mongo:
  image: mongo
  command: --smallfiles
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to control access to the MongoDB container (like with the `--auth` flag), and how to have external access (say a GUI) using a username/password.

The two services get redeployed via **Tutum** by a webhook after a Docker Automated Build. In other words, I don't want to manually configure the database every time.

How do I control access a.k.a. set a root/admin user to secure my MongoDB database using the `Dockerfile` or the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239251/mongodb-docker-container-with-client-access-control

Comment: I ended up using a predefined image called **tutum-docker-mongodb** that has auth enabled by default. The image can be found [here](https://github.com/tutumcloud/mongodb)